# wpf converter binding - dynamic binding in wrong order

Tags: wpf

I am trying to bind a combobox with the Tabitems using converter

My converter class is as follows

```
public class TabItemsCollection : IValueConverter  
{
   >public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
   {  
      ItemCollection collection = value as ItemCollection;  
      IList<string> names = new List<string>();  
      foreach (TabItem ti in collection.SourceCollection)  
      {  
           names.Add(ti.Header.ToString());  
      }  
      return names;  
    }   

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
         throw new NotSupportedException();  
    }  
}
```

My xaml is as follows

//combobox

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbModule" 
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mnuMain, Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource MenuItemsConverter}}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=mnuMain, Path=SelectedIndex}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

//TabControl

```
<local:MenuTab Name="mnuMain"></local:MenuTab>
```

I am binding 'mnuMain' with items which is a custom tabcontrol in codebehind, as i am doing so i am unable to popularate combobox with tabitems because the converter fires first and then the 'mnuMain'. If I create the Tabitems in xaml the combobox is populated with tabitems but my problem is with dynamic binding.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to force your binding to update again:

```
cmbModule.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

Another option is to create a DependecyProperty that holds the collection of tabs and then bind the Combobox and MenuTab to the same property. the SelectedIndex can be done in the same way as you do now.

A third option is to create a property of type ObservableCollection that holds the information that is needed and then create 2 Converters, one to convert to tabitem and 1 to convert to Combobox item. If you add or remove an item from the collection will the binding be triggered automatically.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. While working on a `TextBox` I've used `txtFrequencyEditMode.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource()` to update the source!